# .NET Remoting - Multiple Channel Register on Client

Tags: c#, rmi, remoting, .net-remoting

My application has a working HttpChannel that I can invoke a method on remote server.

Now, in the application, I need to register another HttpChannel that invokes another method on another server.

But the application fails if I don't **unregister the first channel**.

How can I make both of these remotings successfully invoke remote methods?

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar situation and decided to just register a channel only when needed and then unregister it immediately after we were done with it, similar to the disconnected model of ADO.NET where you connect, get the data, and then disconnect.

Per the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkfd3wha%28VS.71%29.aspx):

> - Channels are registered on a per-application-domain basis. A single
>     process can contain multiple application domains. When a process ends,
>     all channels registered by it are automatically destroyed.
> - Channel
>     names must be unique within an application domain. For example,
>     because the default channels have names, to register two HttpChannel
>     objects in one application domain, you must change the names of the
>     channels before registering them. The following C# code example
>     demonstrates this.

```
 IDictionary prop = new Hashtable();
 prop["name"] = "http1";
 prop["port"] = "9001";
 ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(new HttpChannel(prop, null, null));
```

> - You cannot register a channel that listens on a specific port more
>     than once. Even though channels are registered on a
>     per-application-domain basis, different application domains on the
>     same machine cannot register the same channel listening on the same
>     port.
> - If you are not sure about whether a port is available, use 0
>     (zero) when configuring your channel's port and the remoting system
>     will choose an available port for you.
> - Clients can communicate with a
>     remote object using any registered channel. The remoting system
>     ensures that the remote object is connected to the right channel when
>     a client attempts to connect to the object. The client is responsible
>     for calling ChannelServices.RegisterChannel before attempting to
>     communicate with a remote object. If it expects a callback function,
>     the client must register a channel and a port.

So, the Channel 's name has to be unique within your applicaiton domain, and by design, only one http channel can have one port at a time.  You can't have two different channels on the same port.

Comment: Thanks David. But, what happens to the requests that attempt to use the channel that you unregister? Isn't it a problem?

Comment: Yes.  The only option is to register two different channels on two different ports.  Having multiple channels open onteh same port is not allowed, so you have one challen on a port to listen (as the server), and use a different channel to call out to the other server (as the client).

Comment: As a client, do we need to configure "port" or "proxyPort"? And does the server need to make any changes?